# PHP check array using empty() function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm newbie of PHP. I have this input for add pultiple array into MySQL database.

```
<input name="image_url[]" id="ads" type="text" value="">
```

now, I need to check if not empty value send to database.

I check with `empty()` function but this not worked with `name="image_url[]"`.

HTML :

```
<input name="image_url[]" id="upload" type="text" value="">
```

PHP code:

```
if(empty($_POST['image_url'])){

echo 'true';

} else {

echo 'false';

}
```

But always I see output : true. in default my input is blank/empty.

I check and remove [] from input name(name="image_url") and I see `true` output.

I think my problem is input array name.

how do fix this and check for empty value?!

in var_dump($_POST) I see this output:

```
  ["image_url"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
```

**Live DEMO** : http://madenade.besaba.com/php/?action=editnews&id=10

**NOTE**: check in demo with empty value and not empty value! u see output : `false`

Comment: try isset($_POST['image_url'])  to see is the value is  set and is not null

Comment: Read manuals about what is considered `empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an array of values by using `[]` in the input name. If you only need one value, not more of them, then remove the `[]` in the input name, otherwise you'll get an array in `$_POST['image_url']`.

```
<input name="image_url" id="upload" type="text" value="">
```

```
if (empty($_POST['image_url'])) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

---

Otherwise, if you *do* need an array of values, then keeping `[]` in the input name means that `$_POST['image_url']` will contain an array of values, not a single value. You probably want to check each one of them.

```
<input name="image_url[]" id="upload" type="text" value="">
```

```
foreach ($_POST['image_url'] as $image_url) {
    if (empty($image_url)) {
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked ture when we have one input box and this code check if one input box have value send and insert all input box (empty value + not empty value) to database. I need to insert only not empty value to my database. `<input name="image_url[]" id="upload" type="text" value="123"><input name="image_url[]" id="upload" type="text" value="456"><input name="image_url[]" id="upload" type="text" value="">` I need to send only value `123` and `456` to databse.

Comment: @EricFavoni, alright, you can then only keep the values you need in the `if` branch, and remove what you don't need in the `else` branch.

Answer (score 0):

First use Html Like This(If ur entering single Value)

```
<input name="image_url" id="upload" type="text" value="">
```

Then In PHP Code Check Like This

```
    if(isset($_POST['image_url']) && $_POST['image_url'] != ""){

echo 'true';

} else {

echo 'false';

}
```

this will give you required output

Comment: Why `!= ""` instead of `empty()`?